Affected down-slope area
I have a road (polyline) in hilly terrain (using the terrain Living Atlas layer) and I want to determine the area (polygon) that could be impacted by runoff from work on the road. Essentially, I'm looking for a reverse watershed functionality, where I can input the road and find everything downslope until it reaches the lowest point before going back another hill. I've looked through the Spatial Analyst and 3D Analyst toolsets, but nothing seems quite right. Any suggestions on a tool with this functionality or a workflow that might accomplish this?

Are you using ArcGIS or which software?

If you're using ArcGIS Pro with the right license level, you may look at the new Flood Simulation modeling?  Haven't really used it myself, so don't know, but sounds like you might be able to at least somewhat make it do what you're trying for, though that may take a bit of work to get right since your use case wouldn't truly be exactly what it's designed for... https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/mapping/simulation/simulation-in-arcgis-pro.htm

Thanks. I'll check out that flood simulation modeling.
I'm using Pro 3.3 with an Advanced license.
